# Parsing JSON with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Is it possible to handle a JSON response using plain Ajax (i.e. JavaScript, without JQuery)?

In this description: 
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp only Text and XML objects are mentioned, but how to handle a JSON respone?

I just want to use pure JavaScript, without any additional libraries.

This shows me the JSON respone:

```
console.log(xhttp.responseText);
```

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**JSON.parse()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
console.log(JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText));
```